# Open popover if application is launched from notification body after app was terminated

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am trying to open popover if application is launched from notification body after app was terminated. I am tying to do it from `AppDelegate`. I am using `LocalNotifications`. I know how to open specific view if I use action buttons but do not know how to open something if notification body is clicked.

**Edit:** My solution works only if app is not terminated.

**Edit2:** Is it right way to do it?:

For simplicity I am trying to open `viewController` in code but actually I need alert message, for that I am using `JSSAlertView`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
// Override point for customization after application launch.



    if let TappedNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {

        print("The notification is \(TappedNotification)")
        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main") as UIViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
}





return true
```

}

I tried this to detect in which state app is but I can't test it if app is terminated and opened from notification:

```
if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active {
    print("App already open")

} else {
    print("App opened from Notification")
}
```

I tried to add this into `else{` but it does not open specific view:

let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

```
 let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main") as UIViewController
 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
 self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
 self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

I want the same effect like Twitter or Instagram if notification body is clicked it redirects you to post. But in my case I want just popover(modal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your app is terminated and you get the notification and you tap on notification then you get this info by following code and that you need to write code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
    if let TappedNotification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {

        print("The notification is \(TappedNotification)")
        let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main") as UIViewController
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    }
```

if your app is not in background mode or active mode you get this way you set a specific rootview controller for the notification. and back you need to change your rootviewcontroller based on your application flow once you are back from notification View Controller.

After review your sample code i fix with following changes:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
        let tintColor = UIColor(red: 252/255, green: 72/255, blue: 49/255, alpha: 1)
        window!.tintColor = tintColor

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: .Alert , categories: nil))


        let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as! UILocalNotification!
        if (notification != nil) {
                                  print("The notification is \(notification)")

                    let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                    let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Main") as! NotificationViewController

                    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
                    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()


                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "YES NOTIFICITO", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
                    window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    return true


        }else{

            let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let initialViewControlleripad : UIViewController = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("first") as UIViewController
            self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewControlleripad
            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "NO NOTIFICIATION", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            window!.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
             return true
        }

    }
```

Comment: @So if I understand you correct my code should work now. But it is not working. Check my edit. Is it right way?

Comment: there is no need to check if  if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Active { in UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey

Comment: I tried without it and it is not working still. OOh wait. Do I need to set my initial viewcotroller to "Main" ? since it is not actually initial ATM.